# Uncaught Exceoption encountered, error, unexpected '`', expecting ',' or ')' - Type: ParserError with CodeIgniter Web Framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting the below error, once I run the code with CodeIgniter Web Framework.

An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: ParseError

Message: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ')'

Below is my code,

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <?php echo form_open_multipart (action:'',attributes:'',hidden:'')?>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo form_input(data:'categoryName',value:'',extra:'class="form-control"');?>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo form_upload(data:'catDp',value:'',extra:'');?>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo form_submit(data:'Add Category',value:'Add Category',extra:'class="btn btn-primary"');?>
                </div>
            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's syntax error try below updated code. for more info visit:https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <?php echo form_open_multipart (''); ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'categoryName','class'=>'form-control']);?>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo form_upload(['name'=>'catDp']);?>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo form_submit(['class'=>'btn btn-primary','value'=>'Add Category']);?>
                </div>
            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```